# How do I know which Workspace I have open in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I currently have several workspaces open that all look similar. I'm wondering how can I know which Xcode window corresponds to which workspace on the file system.

---

I realize I could close all and re-open them, but I'm hoping there's a way to just tell which is which.

I cannot right-click > "show in finder" an item in the project navigator (e.g. like a project) because this is a workspace that houses several projects.

I tried going to File > Workspace settings, but it doesn't show the name nor the path of the current workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I haven't found a way to find the Workspace path.

Well, there is one. Command-click on the left-most element of the jump bar:

[image]

You will see the entire containing folder hierarchy. If you've done this right, your workspaces will be in different folders, so the name of the containing folder (here, "MyWorkspace") will distinguish them. — Moreover, the name of your workspace is present at in the window's title bar (shown in the screen shot at top right).

Comment: I guess my project is badly misconfigured because I see multiple workspaces in the folders. I also see "Running MyProject on iPhone 11" instead of it being prefixed with the workspace name. Glad to know in the happy path case it's relatively easy to find.

Comment: Yes, it’s odd that it’s so hard to learn the name of the workspace itself. I think I’ve cheated by having the projects together with the workspace file. That might not be the case, so now you’d see the project hierarchy and that wouldn’t help. I think for now your answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to find the Workspace path.

However, you can get the workspace name with either of these methods:

- Find navigator > Click "In Workspace" you should see the name up top.
- When building the project, the first message tells you which workspace it is building.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can go to File->Show in Finder to see the folder where the workspace file has been loaded from.